# Symmetry of $(x - y)(y - b)(b - a)(a - x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

> Determine the symmetric group for $(x - y)(y - b)(b - a)(a - x)$

I've been trying to find this for a while now, but I cannot get the polynomial to a form where I could see this. Fully expanding I  have $$b^2x^2-b^2ax+ba^2x-bax^2+bxy^2-axy^2+2baxy-bx^2y-a^2xy+ax^2y-b^2xy-bay^2+a^2y^2+b^2ay-ba^2y$$

and factoring I get $$\left(xy-bx-y^2+by\right)\left(b-a\right)\left(a-x\right) = \left(xy-bx-y^2+by\right)(ba-bx-a^2+ax)$$

but neither one of these doesn't seem to show any symmetry to me. The term $\left(xy-bx-y^2+by\right)$ it seems that $x$ and $b$ would be symmetric and similarly $y$ and $b$ so for this polynomial I would have $\{e, (xb)(yb)\}$ as the symmetric group. $(ba-bx-a^2+ax)$ would seem to be symmetric with $\{e, (xb)\}$?

Comment: Obviously, we have the cyclic permutation of $(xyba)$.

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous. The polynomial in $\,a,b,x,y\,$ becomes another polynomial if we permute the $\,a,b,x,y.\,$ Some of these polynomials are equal. You need to determine when that happens and mod out by the subgroup which maps the polynomial to itself. The problem  perhaps only allows permuting $\,x,y\,$ in which case it is a lot simpler.